# Non-Typical Date format for excel

Tags: excel, date, formula

I need to convert a date format into a date format that excel understands.  This format I'm using is an export from a military system that spits the date out in a "military style" date format.

I need this: `011000Z OCT20` to equal `01-OCT-20`.

The original format is this: `DD HHMM(time Zone) MMM YY`; so  `01 1000Z(GMT Time) OCT 20`

How can I make Excel recognize this as a date?

Currently, I'm using the Text to column feature to separate out the date, dump the time, then concatenate the multiple column into a date format.  I then have to copy paste the new text into a date formatted column.

I have over 300 rows of date to go through, and its usually 100 rows  weekly.

MACROS are not allowed on my systems.  So this will have to be formulas.

Just looking for a more automated / simplified method that can keep up with the system exports.

Thanks everyone!!

Frank

Answer (score 1):

If one has TEXTJOIN:

```
=--TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{1,4,5}&"]"))
```

Depending on one's version this may require the formula to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

then format the cell: `dd-mmm-yy`

[image]

Comment: That is awesome!  I love excel sometimes...

However, the actual format is as follows: 021000Z SEP 20

My apologies about that.  I wanted to be clear about the meaning of the format...  Also, would you be able to explain the parts of that formula for my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

```
=--REPLACE(A1,3,5,"")
```

will remove the time portion and convert to a date.

You'll need to format the result as a date